# android external storage issue

Tags: android

Im on a stage where i will publish my created app now. But i have a problem. You see when i use anDroid.permission.write_external_storage it doesnt work. my app still automatically installed on the phone memory and not on the sd card.. is there a way to automatically install it on sdcrad? If posible how? cause the permision i use dont work. my android version is 2.3.

this is my manifest..

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<supports-screens
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"        
 />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission has nothing to do with where your application is going to be installed..

read here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html

Comment: Thank you soooo much.. i thought it was the permission.. Thanks again